# Consecutive photos are deleted

Tags: photos, gallery, google-photos

I have setup google photos as my gallery app on a Nokia 5.3.
Whenever I take consecutive photos, like for instance trying to photograph multiple pages of a book, or just taking multiple pictures in a row, only the first one will be saved. If I click on some of the subsequent ones in the little gallery preview in the camera app, they will show as "Processing" for a few seconds, and then just disappear, they're not on my phone (from what I can see at least) nor on the photos.google.com page.
I'm sure it's just some obvious setting I'm missing somewhere, but I can't seem to find anything anywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure Google Photos is relevant here. Since the little gallery preview in the camera app also has a problem, this really looks like an issue with the camera app and file writing (possibly corrupted data, I have experienced a similar issue with a solid-gray-image when using some 3rd-party camera apps).

Comment: I'm honestly not really sure what information is relevant. Googling around most information i could find was actually people that wanted similar functionaliy (deleting duplicate images) with most answers pointing to google photos as a solution. I've tried moving image storage to sd card in the camera app, without any change. So I wont rule out that it is a file writing issue, but even so, what is the issue and how would I fix it? I think the preview button uses the gallery app to open the image on clicking, btw.

Comment: default camera app has setting for change storage location to MicroSD Card. On the same settings I remember there was an initial note that consecutive photos still get saved to phone internal storage only (most likely because of speed limitation). maybe you can find pictures in `/sdcard` which is your Internal Storage. you can also try some disk digger [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.i8dudata.imgrecover.free) to find any existing files